# Partial lookup for cell contents from one column in a different column

Tags: r, regex

I am working n R, using R studio,

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. 
Column A contains passenger iD, 
B contains passenger name, 
C contains husband name.

I am attempting to create a new column which look to see if the husband name in column C is listed in any of the records in column B. If so it should then return to me the passenger iD of the husband from column A.

To make things more complicated, as in the first example in some cases, the husband's given in column C might not include the his second name, which would be included in column B.

```
library(stringr)
rm(list=ls())
passengerid <- c(0908,9883,7767,3302)

Name<- c("Backstrom, Mrs. Karl Alfred (Maria Mathilda Gustafsson)",
          "Backstrom, Mr. Karl Alfred John",
          "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",
          "Cumings, Mr. John Bradley")

HusbandName <- c("Backstrom, Mr. Karl Alfred","","Cumings, Mr. John
Bradley","")



df1<- data.frame(cbind(passengerid,Name,HusbandName))
df1$Name <- as.character(df1$Name)
df1$HusbandName <- as.character(df1$HusbandName)
```

I have tried using Stringr, but facing problems because 1)I need the code to look at only 1 element of the vector HusbandName and search for it in the whole vector Name. 2) I found it difficult to use regular expressions given that the pattern I am looking for is vectorised (as HusbandName)

This is what I have tried so far:

## Attempt 1 - only finds exact matches &  doesn't return the passengerID & doesn't add column to df

```
df1$Husbandid < - for (i in 1:NROW(df1$HusbandName)) {
print(HusbandName[i] %in% Name)}
```

## Attempt 2 - finds partial matches, but does not ignore blanks & does not tell me passenger id & doesn't add column to df

```
df1$Husbandid <- for (i in 1:NROW(df1$HusbandName)) {
print(which(str_detect(df1$Name,df1$HusbandName[i])))}
```

#Attempt 3 - almost works but - the printed results are different from those added into the dataframe as a new column. how can i correct for this? Ultimately I need the ones in the df to be correct. the error is that those without husbands are showing husbandiD when this should be blank or na. can this be corrected or is there a way to convert the output of the for loop into a vector we can add to the df?

```
 for (i in 1:NROW(df1$HusbandName)) {
     if (df1$HusbandName[i] =="") {
      print("Man") & next() 
      }
    FoundHusbandNames<- c(which(str_detect(df1$Name,df1$HusbandName[i])))
    print(df1$passengerid[FoundHusbandNames]) -> df1$Husbandid[i] }
```

Comment: Please share what you tried, maybe you were close enough and that will show what problem you are having.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - done

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the id where the names actually match, as for Cumings. It won't work for Backstrom though. Not sure if you missed off the 'John' at the end of Karl Alfred or if the data is inconsistent. If the former, this should be fine.

```
library(dplyr)
husbands <- df1[, c(1, 2)] %>% filter(HusbandName == '')
colnames(husbands)[2] <- "HusbandName"
df2 <- left_join(df1, husbands, by = "HusbandName")
View(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is 1 step closer, but the data is inconsistent, so in some cases - the husband's given in column C might not include his second name, which would be included in column B, hence why I think a partial match is needed

Comment: You could try looking into the fuzzyjoin package

Comment: Anyone able to help on this?

I have now managed to get close - I am using a For & IF loop and I am getting the results printed onto the screen --> can't figure out how to turn the results into a vector I can then Cbind into a column